# How to define plugin settings in babel 6?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I've tried to use babel 5.x style, with `extra` option but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins can specify options. You can do so in your config by wrapping it in an array and providing a options object. For example:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-async-to-module-method", {
      module: 'bluebird',
      method: 'coroutine'
    }]
  ]
}
```

From https://github.com/babel/babel.github.io/pull/513